# Hosting Silverlight Control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, webbrowser-control, pivotviewer

In my WPF application I am using a Web Browser control, which is showing a Silverlight application. I have to go with this design(Web Browser and Silverlight) because,  I badly need PivotViewer control, which only available on Silverlight.

Now, I need to communicate from WPF to silverlight app which was in Web Browser control (i.e. Pass an .NET List/Class).

How can I do it? and What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is built around a *Silverlight* control, why are you hosting it in *WPF*? Wouldn't it be simpler to just have a [*Silverlight Desktop Application*](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx)?

Comment: I thought about it. My application using Local File Systems, Databases connections (SQL LocalDB) etc.